# Sorting ListActivity through a CheckBox

Tags: android

I have 2 options of sorting on my `ListActivity` through a `CheckBox`.
The default sorting is when the `CheckBox` is unchecked, by sorting the nearby places on the List based on its distance with the user and the other one when the `CheckBox` is checked, the entry on the List will be sorted alphabetically from A-Z.

So by default, when the user opens the app, the checkbox is unchecked and the ListView should be sorted based on 'Nearby'.

Both methods I have work perfectly based on the click on the checkbox when I don't call any of the sort method inside the `ListViewAdapter`. That means, at first the entries on the List aren't sorted but when the `CheckBox` is checked it will sort the list alphabetically, when the it's unchecked it will be sorted based on 'Nearby'.

But when I call the `sortNearby()` method inside the `ListViewAdapter`, the alphabet sort method doesn't work at all. The ListView stays sorted based on 'Nearby'.

What do I need to do to enable the alphabet sorting method update on the ListView when I click the CheckBox?

Here's how I call the sort method based on a click on the CheckBox and the method themselves:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (view == findViewById(R.id.cb_tab_sort)) {
             if (view.isSelected()){
                    view.setSelected(false);
                    sortNearby();
                    videoLocationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

             } else {
                    view.setSelected(true);
                    sortAZ();
                    videoLocationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }        
       }

    }

    public void sortAZ(){
        Arrays.sort(videoLocations, new Comparator<VideoLocation>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(VideoLocation lhs, VideoLocation rhs) {
                return lhs.name.compareTo(rhs.name);
            }
        });
    }

    public void sortNearby(){
        Arrays.sort(videoLocations, new Comparator<VideoLocation>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(VideoLocation lhs, VideoLocation rhs) {

                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                double lng = location.getLongitude();

                double lat1 = lhs.latitude;
                double lng1 = lhs.longitude;

                double lat2 = rhs.latitude;
                double lng2 = rhs.longitude;

                double lhsDistance = countDistance(lat,lng,lat1,lng1);
                double rhsDistance = countDistance(lat,lng,lat2,lng2);
                if (lhsDistance < rhsDistance) 
                    return -1;
                else if (lhsDistance > rhsDistance) 
                    return 1;
                else return 0;
            }
        });
    }
```

and here's how I call the sorting method inside the ListViewAdapter

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LocationsListActivity.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listitems, null, true);
        }


        final VideoLocation vidLocation = videoLocations[position];


        //Image
        ImageView v = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        String url = vidLocation.documentary_thumbnail_url;
        v.setTag(url);
        loader.DisplayImage(url, LocationsListActivity.this, v);

        //Title
        TextView titleView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
        String title = vidLocation.name;
        titleView.setText(title.toUpperCase());
        Typeface fontRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "miso-regular.ttf");
        titleView.setTypeface(fontRegular);

        //Description
        TextView descView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_list_desc);
        String desc = vidLocation.text;
        descView.setText(desc);
        Typeface fontLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "miso-light.ttf");
        descView.setTypeface(fontLight);

        //More
        TextView more = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_more);
        more.setText(getString(R.string.de_list_more));
        more.setTypeface(fontLight);

        //Distance
        final TextView distanceView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_distance);
        distanceView.setTypeface(fontRegular);


        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager == null) {
            Toast.makeText(LocationsListActivity.this,
                    "Location Manager Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        location = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location == null)
            location = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {

            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude(); 

            double lat2 = roundDown(vidLocation.latitude);
            double lng2 = roundDown(vidLocation.longitude);


            if (countDistance(lat,lng,lat2,lng2)>= 500){
                double kilometer = countDistance(lat,lng,lat2,lng2) /1000;
                int decimalPlaces = 1;
                BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(kilometer);
                decimal = decimal.setScale(decimalPlaces, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
                double new_km= decimal.doubleValue();
                distanceView.setText(new_km+" km");
            }
            else
            {
                int decimalPlaces = 1;
                BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(countDistance(lat,lng,lat2,lng2));
                decimal = decimal.setScale(decimalPlaces, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
                double meter= decimal.doubleValue();
                distanceView.setText(meter +" m");
            }
        }

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
                location = l;
                locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                if (l.getLatitude() == 0 || l.getLongitude() == 0) {
                } else {
                    double lat = l.getLatitude();
                    double lng = l.getLongitude(); 

                    double lat2 = roundDown(vidLocation.latitude);
                    double lng2 = roundDown(vidLocation.longitude);


                    if (countDistance(lat,lng,lat2,lng2)>= 500){
                        double kilometer = countDistance(lat,lng,lat2,lng2) /1000;
                        int decimalPlaces = 1;
                        BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(kilometer);
                        decimal = decimal.setScale(decimalPlaces, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
                        double new_km= decimal.doubleValue();
                        distanceView.setText(new_km+" km");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int decimalPlaces = 1;
                        BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(countDistance(lat,lng,lat2,lng2));
                        decimal = decimal.setScale(decimalPlaces, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
                        double meter= decimal.doubleValue();
                        distanceView.setText(meter +" m");
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, locationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, locationListener);
        locationtimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 5000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if (location != null)
                    locationtimer.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                if (location == null) {
                }
            }
        };
        locationtimer.start();
                sortNearby();
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do it inside the adapter?  If you want an initial sort just make a call to the method before you set the adapter.

Comment: because I obtain the distance inside the adapter, there are attributes like the object's latitude and longitude which are initialized inside the adapter to calculate the distance. Otherwise if I call the sortNearby() inside onCreate, it gives me NullPointerException

Comment: The function of your adapter is to create views for each datas inside your Object List. You must not play with datas inside. That's why your datas must be initialized in your Model, not inside your adapter. Why did you initialize datas inside adapter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to remove `sortNearby();` in your getView method ?

You must not call this inside the getView method.

Comment: Yes but then the list isn't sorted based on 'Nearby' by default. Where should I call it? The thing is I need the entries on my ListView is sorted Nearby by default everytime the user opens the app.

Comment: Before sending datas in your ListAdapter, just call you `sortNearby();` method

Comment: because I obtain the distance inside the adapter, there are attributes like the object's latitude and longitude which are initialized inside the adapter to calculate the distance. Otherwise if I call the sortNearby() inside onCreate, it gives me NullPointerException

Comment: The function of your adapter is to create views for each datas inside your Object List. You must not play with datas inside. That's why your datas must be initialized in your Model, not inside your adapter. Why did you initialize datas inside adapter ?

Comment: Hi Alexandre, no I mean not initialize, but I call the data from my ObjectList inside the adapter. Because some TextViews on the listitems layout has to be set with the attributes of the Model. Anyway I just updated my question, check out the full version of my Adapter. Maybe you can suggest me a better way to do deal with the distance method, so I'm able to call the sortNearby() method inside onCreate(). Pls have a look

Comment: What your are doing is wrong. Imagine, each time that your ListView must read inflate view (for each Object in your ObjectList), your are asking the device to get location and do some stuff.
You should put this away from the adapter, and put it in your model class. Something that you could do too, is to initialize your location in onStart method, and create a method like initializeWithLocation(Location location) in your VideoLocations variable wich contains all VideoLocation object. In this case, you will be able to initialize distance in each VideoLocation.